# Swift (IOS): Saving and Reading Data into/from a file

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm trying to save data into a txt file in Swift. But so far I have not managed to do it.
I am using a code already posted here, but I don't know what am I doing wrong.

I attached this code to a button action, so when I press the button It should work:

```
let file = "file.txt" //this is the file. we will write to and read from it

let text = "some text" //just a text

    if let dir : NSString = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true).first {
let path = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(file);

//writing
do {
    try text.writeToFile(path, atomically: false, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
}
catch {/* error handling here */}

//reading
do {
    let text2 = try NSString(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
}
catch {/* error handling here */}
}
```

I have some things which I do not understand, like where is file file.txt, and can If doesn't exist does the program creates it?

Comment: I am using this code now and It worked:

// Set the file path
let path = "myfile.txt"

// Set the contents
let contents = "Here are my file's contents"

do {
    // Write contents to file
    try contents.writeToFile(path, atomically: false, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
}
catch let error as NSError {
    print("Ooops! Something went wrong: \(error)")
}

Comment: But how can I append new data into a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actualy there in xcode project directory ie you have to move your file file.txt to your Xcode-project (Use drag'n'drop and check "Copy files if necessary").

Comment: I dragged it before. But nothing happens. There is no written text in the file  :(